# Adding CoreData to existing Project

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I am trying to add CoreData to an existing project and
there is strange error...

I get the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   'Cannot create an
>   NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a
>   nil model'

in RootView there is a warning in:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController;
```

in line:

```
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
```

and it says:

> warning: class 'RootViewController'
>   does not implement the
>   'NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate'
>   protocol

any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

argh!

sorry for even asking, I just missed that I changed the name of .xcdatamodel

I needed just to change the name in managedObjectModel and persistentStoreCoordinator

hope it'll help someone anyway.

Comment: Everyone learns from mistakes, usually our own. If not, we can always hope we serve as a warning to others.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same exception.

My issue was that I had added the `.xcdatamodeld` file in the root directory of the project (with siblings `Frameworks` and `Products`) instead of in the folder named after the project (with siblings `Supporting Files`, `AppDelegate.h`, etc.)

I tracked it down to this line: `NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Foo" withExtension:@"momd"];`

In this method: `- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel`

Comment: I had the same problem, to change it's location though you must also change the Path property in the Utilities editor to "Relative to Group".

Comment: Thanks for this. I renamed @"Foo" to the name of my .xcdatamodeld file, and moved the .xcdatamodeld file my root project directory. You may also need to do this in the terminal.